# SQl error with timeout

Tags: c#, sql, timeout

I have been having trouble with timeout on SQL program , I have narrowed it down to this function , i can pass parameters and it words , but in this instance I send a couple hundered . When it runs I get a timeout and maybe 6 or so get through into the database and then timeout occurs in about 2minutes. when run locally everything works fine and operations complete in a few seconds.!! any ideas? .

I know its getting the information it needs and gettting into the list and it can connect and send data to SQL. I have read maybe creating too many connections and the like but nothing seems to fix it. Any ideas or simple problems you have come accross?. also tried disabling debuggers etc as per

```
public void ConnectToSQl(String word, int count, String HashTag = " ")
{
    checkExcludeList();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = dev\\SQLEXPRESS ;" +
                            "Initial Catalog=sml;" + 
                            "User id=**** ;" + 
                            "Password =******;" + 
                            "Trusted_Connection=No";
    try {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO word_list (word , count)" +
                                            "VALUES (@word , @count)", conn);
        //add parameters for insert
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", word);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", count);
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Box.Text = "SQL error" + e;
    } finally {
       conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify i get a HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.] Error.

Comment: Are you calling ConnectToSQL inside a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing in your open connection.  Opening a sql connection is very expensive.

```
public void ConnectToSQl(SqlConnection conn, String word, int count, String HashTag = " ")
{   
    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        throw new SqlExecutionException("Sqlconnection is not open");

    checkExcludeList();

    SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO word_list (word , count)" +
        "VALUES (@word , @count)", conn);

    //add parameters for insert
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", word);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", count);

    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Comment: Yes figured it out i was using ConnectToSQL like stuarmclark said, inside a while loop so it was very expensive doing that. instead i gathered the output and using the one connection pass through the list. So Silly and obvious. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Why did it work so fast when running locally though?. the machine i am running and the SQL server are on different machines, while when i deploy they reside in the same machine!. just be good to know. thanks .

Comment: Sql limits the number of database connections. It is possible that in your deployment environment it cant open a new connection until some other process closes its connection.  If you run sp_who2 on that database, you will see all of the open connections.  If you see more than about 60, you might have a problem with your sql connection management.